# TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution in django

Tags: python, django

I am learning django through the 'Django 3 by example' book, and right now i am trying to build an e - learning platform. But, I am getting a weird error in my views.py file.

Here is my views file:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin
from .models import Course


class ManageCourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'educa/manage/educa/list.html'
    permission_required = 'educa.view_course'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)


class OwnerMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.owner)


class OwnerEditMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.onwer = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class OwnerCourseMixin(object, LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin):
    model = Course
    fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')


class OwnerCourseEditMixin(OwnerCourseMixin, OwnerEditMixin):
    template_name = 'educa/manage/course/list.html'


class CourseCreateView(OwnerEditMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'educa.add_course'


class CourseUpdateView(OwnerCourseEditMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'educa.change_course'


class CourseDeleteView(OwnerCourseMixin, DeleteView):
    template_name = 'educa/manage/course/delete.html'
    permission_required = 'educa.delete_course'
```

The error is on line 30.
Here is the full error message:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\elearn\elearn\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('course/',include('educa.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\elearn\educa\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import *
  File "C:\Users\Padma Jain\Desktop\django\educa\elearn\educa\views.py", line 30, in <module>
    class OwnerCourseMixin(object, LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases object, LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin
```

And just if it is required, here is the urls.py file of the educa application:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('mine/',ManageCourseListView.as_view(),name='manage_course_list'),
    path('create/',CourseCreateView.as_view(),name='course_create'),
    path('<pk>/edit/',CourseUpdateView.as_view(),name='course_edit'),
    path('<pk>/delete/',CourseDeleteView.as_view(),name='course_delete'),
]
```

This is my first time building such a large application. Can someone please tell where I'm wrong?

**EDIT**:
I solved this problem by editing line 30 of my views.py file from this:

```
class OwnerCourseMixin(object, LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin):
   ....
```

to this:

```
class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin):
    ....
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `object` to be inherited

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. But do I need to inherit anything instead of object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Python, every class inherits from a built-in basic class called `object`.**

Your `OwnerCourseMixin`  is inheriting from `object` **and** some other class. Because the other class(es), in this case, `LoginRequiredMixin` and `PermissionRequiredMixin`, already inherit from `object`, Python now cannot determine what class to look methods up on first.

You don't need to inherit from `object` here.

```py
class OwnerCourseMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin):
    model = Course
    fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I have edited my question accordingly

Comment: Sure. Wait a bit.

Comment: Just a small tip: If you encounter an error, just copy it and Google it. Somebody else is bound to have already experienced it, so it saves a lot of time for you (and pressure, if you're like me. I freak out at the smallest unexpected error.).